# Error when trying to use external link in Phonegap on iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying to use external link(`http://192.168.1.142/jasmine-device_2/login.html`)  in phonegap using `cordova2.0.0`

It works fine for this local

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

But showing error 
`ERROR:Start Page at 'http://192.168.1.142/jasmine-device_2/login.html' was not found.`    for below

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"http://192.168.1.142/jasmine-device_2";
self.viewController.startPage = @"login.html";
```

How can i use external link in iPhone. Moreover this external link is working fine in `android` phonegap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u add the url in plist file, if no try this

Go to the plist file (in xcode /Supporting Files/cordova.plist) ,You need to add the string as a child node of ExternalHosts. To do this, first click on the little arrow to the left of the ExternalHosts label so that the arrow points downwards (this is crucial). Then right-click on the ExternalHosts label and click on "Add Row". Then set the new row value to whatever you want